# How to know an object address in a method?

Tags: c++

For example I have this class:

```
class example{
public:
       int beauty;
      void CompareObject(const example& another_object, example*& ptr);
};
```

The method CompareObject() compares this object with the object another_object, (by reference) and saves the address of the most beautiful object in the pointer ptr (also passed by reference)

The problem is in CompareExampleObject:

```
void CompareExampleObject (const example& another_object, example*& ptr){
    // set the best object
    if(beauty < another_object.beauty)
        ptr = &another_object;
    else
        ptr = // !!! What should I write here?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is the address of the object inside a method of the object.

Comment: thanks very much. I feel so sad to have asked a so easy question, but I am still a newbie in C++...

Comment: If you found the answer useful, once you have 15 rep, you can click the arrow at the top left of the answer and upvote it.  You can also "accept" the answer by clicking on the grey tick mark in the left margin - you should probably wait a bit, and see if there is a better answer.